# Who is the fastest: for, while , str.count

Tags: python

```
#1st solution 
m = num 
cnt = 0 
while m>0: 
   if m%10 == 0: 
       cnt = cnt+1 
   m = m//10 

#2nd solution 
cnt =0 
snum = str(num) 
for digit in snum: 
    if digit == "0": 
        cnt = cnt+1 

#3rd solution 
cnt = str.count(str(num), "0")
```

using `time.clock()`,(finding t1-t2 for each solution ) it seems always that `for` is the fastest is that right? and why is that so?

Comment: Don't benchmark with `time.clock`. Benchmark with `timeit`.

Comment: Why a screen capture? Why? Why? Oh, why?

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes probably a homework question

Comment: It would be easier to help if instead of a screenshot you would provide a copyable text.

Comment: Before trying to explain empirical results - make sure they are [**statistical significant**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance). Are they?

Comment: @Schorsch So? (S)he could put on a little bit of effort!

Comment: @ amit for each time I run it shows different results...so there isn't such thing who is the fastest among those three?

Comment: @user7777777 test the 3 methods for different number sizes (say 0, 10, 100, 1000, 1000000). Check the results for each method. Then reason...

Comment: @ it seems that for bigger numbers the 3rd solution is the best...however not for all cases...

Comment: @user7777777 Tends to happen all the time! That's why they teach us about algorithmic efficiency in CS courses and why they make us compare different algorithms over **different sample sizes** ;-)

Comment: The three methods are roughly equivalent though (as far as we know; we don't see the way `str.count` is implemented). They're all in the same best/worst case order... so, why would one of them be much faster than the others? Hhmmm...

Answer (score 1):

Apprantly `str(num).count('0')` is the best.

Use [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to benchmark:

```
In [303]: timeit str(num).count('0')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 us per loop

In [304]: %%timeit
     ...: m = num
     ...: cnt = 0
     ...: while m > 0:
     ...:     if m % 10 == 0:
     ...:         cnt = cnt+1
     ...:     m = m // 10
     ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.6 us per loop

In [306]: %%timeit
     ...: cnt = 0
     ...: snum = str(num)
     ...: for digit in snum:
     ...:     if digit == '0':
     ...:         cnt +=1
     ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.11 us per loop
```